# Strapi issue /i18n/locales 404

Tags: node.js, next.js, strapi

### Bug report

#### Required System information

- Node.js version: v16.17.1
- NPM version: 8.15.0
- Strapi version: 4
- Database: mysql
- Operating system: o2switch

#### Describe the bug

I'm trying to deploy a strapi app on o2switch using Nodejs (and Mysql) for a Nextjs app.

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

Each time I connect to my admin panel this error appears

#### Screenshots

[image]

Before log in

[image]

#### Code snippets

.env :

```
APP_HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=1338
```

./config/server.js:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({   host: env('APP_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),   port: env.int('PORT', 1337),   app: {     keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),   }, });
```

I've tried to configure `server.js` and `.env` but nothing changed